# Logic question linking $\omega$-categoricalness to completeness

Tags: logic

***Please check my attempted "answer" below. Any corrections are gladly welcomed!***

I am stuck with this problem:

Assume that $T$ is a consistent theory of a first order language $\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{A}$. Assume that every model of $T$ is infinite. Show that if $T$ is $\omega$-categorical, then $T$ is complete.

---

The problem I am facing is that, according to my lecture notes, the definition of $\omega$-categorical requires $T$ to be complete in the first place.
 (Definition: Suppose that $T$ is a complete, consistent theory. $T$ is $\omega$-categorical if and only if any two countable models of $T$ are isomorphic.)

---

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: Redefine $\omega$-completeness by removing the requirement that $T$ is complete in the definition from your notes.

Comment: Do you mean $\omega$-categorical?

Comment: Yes, sorry, no coffee today yet.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the answer below and I don't know how to delete comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better: A consistent theory $T$ is $\omega$-categorical if and only if any two countable models of T are isomorphic.

To show if $T$ is $\omega$-categorical then complete, prove the contrapositive. Suppose $T$ is not complete. Then for some $\varphi$, $T + \varphi$ and $T + \neg\varphi$ are both consistent, so by Löwenheim-Skolem both have countable models which can't be isomorphic ...

Comment: As Yoyostein notes, we need to use the completeness theorem to show that the theories have models before we can apply the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter Smith. I attempt to elaborate more on his answer (to improve my understanding and to practice logic notation, which I am weak and unfamiliar with). Please give any comments on whether it is correct, it is the only way that I can check if I am on the right track. Sincere thanks!

---

Suppose to the contrary $T$ is not complete.

Then there exists a sentence $\varphi$ such that $\varphi\notin T$ and $(\neg\varphi)\notin T$.

Then, we claim that $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ and $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ are both consistent. (not sure how to show that)

Hence, by Gödel's completeness theorem, $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ and $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ are both satisfiable.

There exists $\mathcal{M}_1$, $\mathcal{M}_2$ such that $\mathcal{M}_1\models T\cup\{\varphi\}$ and $\mathcal{M}_2\models T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$.

By Lowenheim-Skolem, there exists elementary substructures $\mathcal{N}_1\leq\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2\leq\mathcal{M}_2$, with $\mathcal{N}_1,\mathcal{N}_2$ countable.

Then, $\mathcal{N}_1\models T\cup\{\varphi\}$ and $\mathcal{N}_2\models T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$

In particular, we have $\mathcal{N}_1\models T$ and $\mathcal{N}_2\models T$, 
so $\mathcal{N}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2$ are two countable models.

But $\mathcal{N}_1\models\varphi$ while $\mathcal{N}_2\models (\neg\varphi)$.

Hence, $\mathcal{N}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2$ are not isomorphic. (Contradiction)

Hence $T$ is complete.